# Get User Stories for each Release Feature Lookback API

Tags: rally, appsdk2, lookbackapi

I need to add some customization to BurnDownApp. 
and I want to retrieve all User Stories for Release from 'Release Combobox' + All Users stories which linked to Portfolio Item features which linked to release.

In default implementation I can retrieve only User Stories which linked to Release:

```
 find: {
    "_TypeHierarchy": { '$in' : [ -51038] },
    "Children": null
    }
```

I tried to use this query:

```
find:{
$and:
[{"_TypeHierarchy": -51038, "Children": null},
{"_TypeHierarchy": { '$in' : [ -51038, -51006 ] },
"Children": null
"Feature.Release.Name": "%ReleaseName%"}]
}
```

but it doesn't work

How I should change query for get needed data?

Link to BurnDownApp on github: https://github.com/RallyApps/app-catalog/tree/master/src/apps/charts/burndown

Answer (score 0):

Even though a WS API query `(Feature.Release.Name = "r3")` will work:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/hierarchicalrequirement?workspace=https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/workspace/12345&query=(Feature.Release.Name = "r3")
```

This will not work in Lookback API.

This Lookback API query `"Feature":7777` will work. In this example 7777 is ObjectID of a feature:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/v2.0/service/rally/workspace/12345/artifact/snapshot/query.js?find={"_ProjectHierarchy":22222,"_TypeHierarchy":"HierarchicalRequirement","ScheduleState":"Accepted","Feature":7777,"_PreviousValues.ScheduleState":{ "$lt":"Accepted"}},sort:[{"ObjectID": 1},{_ValidFrom: 1}]&fields=["Name","ScheduleState","PlanEstimate","Release"]&hydrate=["ScheduleState"]
```

If you want to get features in the custom app dynamically based on a release combobox selection you may:

1. Use wsapi data store to find those features (get their OIDs), and then
2. Use snapshot to get historical data on stories that associated with features. Filtering them based on `"Feature": {$in:[7777,8888,9999]}` in the `find` should work.